# Translating Plotly Dash to other language

Tags: python, localization, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have made a dashboard in Plotly Dash. Everything looks perfect, however the main problem I am facing is that of localization(translating the elements in Dashboard to other language). Without translating, the dashboard will be worthless. I have tried following method for translating the elements:

```
@app.callback(
Output('1', 'children' ),
Output('2', 'children' ),

Input("lang-dropdown", "value"))
def update_card(value):

if value=='Ar':
    return 'مقارنة المبيعات', 'ضبط المبيعات'
else:
    return 'Sales Comparison', 'Sales Tuning'
```

However, there are lot of elements and I want it to translate it more efficiently like that used in other language(like in json format). I have looked into other methods like Flask Babel translating as well, but I am a beginner and it is difficult for me to do it at this stage. Can someone please guide me how can I localize my dashboard? Will be grateful.

Comment: it looks like text in dataset so you should rather translate dateset before you use Dash

Comment: If you have some sort of structure for your translations like for example: `translations = {"Ar": ['مقارنة المبيعات', 'ضبط المبيعات'], "En": ['Sales Comparison', 'Sales Tuning']}` you could return something like `translations[value]` in your callback.